# On ViewPager, start Animation on Fragment on onPageSelected

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with a FragmentPageAdapter. When a fragment is displayed, I want it to start an animation (fade-in a view in the fragment).

However, the animation runs inconsistently, it runs on every few pages when I swipe left/right. I think I need to start the animation on the onPageSelected event but I can't figure out how to get the fragment and start the animation.

My code is below. TourFragment is the fragment I add to the ViewPager using the FragmentPageAdapter while TourActivty contains the ViewPager.

TourFragment

```
public class TourFragment extends Fragment  {

    Tour tour;
    ImageView ivTitle;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tour,
            container, false);

    RelativeLayout rlImageContainer = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tour_image_container);

    Resources resources = getActivity().getResources();

    ivTitle = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tour_title);
    ivTitle.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(tour.getDrawableTitleId()));

    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fadein);
    ivTitle.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fadein);
    ivTitle.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );
}



public static Fragment newInstance(Tour tour) {

    TourFragment f = new TourFragment();
    f.tour = tour;
    return f;
}
}
```

TourActivity

```
public class TourActivity extends FragmentActivity {

MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
String tourType;
Drawable drawableSelected;
Drawable drawableNotSelected;
LinearLayout llIndicators;
int prevPagePosition = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tour);

    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
        });
    }

    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    List<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();

        messages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.guess_tour_messages);
        Tour tour = new Tour();
        tour.setDrawableImageId(R.drawable.tu_guest_image_1);
        tour.setDrawableTitleId(R.drawable.tu_guest_text_1);
        tour.setMessage(messages[0]);
        tour.setPageIndex(0);
        tour.setTotalPages(messages.length);
        tours.add(tour);

        tour = new Tour();
        tour.setDrawableImageId(R.drawable.tu_guest_image_2);
        tour.setDrawableTitleId(R.drawable.tu_guest_text_2);
        tour.setMessage(messages[1]);
        tour.setPageIndex(1);
        tour.setTotalPages(messages.length);
        tours.add(tour);

        tour = new Tour();
        tour.setDrawableImageId(R.drawable.tu_guest_image_3);
        tour.setDrawableTitleId(R.drawable.tu_guest_text_3);
        tour.setMessage(messages[2]);
        tour.setPageIndex(2);
        tour.setTotalPages(messages.length);
        tours.add(tour);

        tour = new Tour();
        tour.setDrawableImageId(R.drawable.tu_guest_image_4);
        tour.setDrawableTitleId(R.drawable.tu_guest_text_4);
        tour.setMessage(messages[3]);
        tour.setPageIndex(3);
        tour.setTotalPages(messages.length);
        tours.add(tour);


    for (Tour tour : tours) {
        fList.add(TourFragment.newInstance(tour));
    }


    return fList;
}

}

class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use in your fragment

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) { 
        Log.v(TAG, "run now");
            Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_view);
            iv.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
            animationFadeIn.setFillAfter(true);
    }
    else {  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

On onPageSelected, I used getView from the fragment to get the view that I want to animate.

```
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            View v = pageAdapter.getItem(position).getView();

            ImageView ivTitle = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tour_title);

            Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(TourActivity.this, R.anim.fadein);
            ivTitle.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Although I very much like this method for it's shear crafty approach, it is prone to null exceptions at runtime. In my case, attempting to achieve a similar result as OP I found BaDo's answer to be the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `FragmentPagerAdapter` implementation you you need to override `public Object instantiateItem(viewGroup container, int index)`.  In the base class fragments are only added with a `FragmentManager` instance when the adapter is first created.  Whenever you page away the offscreen fragments are detached but not removed.  The `FragmentManager` caches the instances with a tag on the object.  They are then attached when they are paged back to.  The default implementation of `instantiateItem` item tags each `Fragment` inside of the `FragmentAdapter` with a hardcoded tag.  You need to tag each `Fragment` you use with a unique tag.  With this is place you can retrieve fragment instances from any `FragmentManager` instance in your app with `public abstract Fragment findFragmentByTag (String tag)`.

```
String[] tags = {"tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4", "tag5"};

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int index) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tags[index]);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = getItem(index);
        ft.add(container.getId(), fragment, mTags[index]);
    }
    else {
        ft.attach(fragment);
    }

    ft.commit();

    return fragment;
}

public String getTag(int index) {
    return mTags[index];
}
```

You should be able to access the the instances in `onPageSelected` now.

Comment: Josh: Thanks for the answer. It turns out I get just use getView from the Fragment. I added my solution to the post.

Comment: Cool, if you end up doing anything with nested fragments with their own backstack within the pager or if you need to animate the transition itself remember my answer.  I had to figure this out for the Rockbot app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and here what solved it:
[Animation of nested fragment within ViewPager fragment is triggered before render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938252/6241054)

In context of your case the same solution would look like this:

java:

```
v.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    ivTitle.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation)
  }
})
```

kotlin:

```
v.post(Runnable {
  ivTitle.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation)
})
```

It ensures that the view is indeed drawn