# Animation of nested fragment within ViewPager fragment is triggered before render

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin, android-animation

I have a `ViewPager` fragment

```
class PagerFragment() : Fragment() {
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

      val pagerView = view as ViewPager
      val adapter = PagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, items)
      pagerView.adapter = adapter
  }
}
```

with the following adapter

```
class PagerAdapter(val fm: FragmentManager, val items: ArrayList<Item>)
    : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        val item = items[position]
        return NestedFragment.newInstance(item)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return  items.size
    }
}
```

which nests fragments with a few animations triggered `onViewCreated` the following way:

```
class NestedFragment() : Fragment() {
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

      val one = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.one)
      val two = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.two)
      val three = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.three)

      view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pic).startAnimation(one)
      view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.content).startAnimation(two)
      view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img).startAnimation(three)
  }
}
```

However often by the time the nested fragment is showed on the screen the animation has already started or even ended :(

Is there a way to determine when the fragment is indeed rendered on the screen of the device?
Of course any other useful suggestions to overcome the issue are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

```
class NestedFragment() : Fragment() {
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

      val one = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.one)
      val two = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.two)
      val three = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.three)
      view.post(Runnable {
        /* 
          If the animation doesn't trigger you may try to hide 
          elements visibility and reveal them before animation starts
        */
        view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pic).startAnimation(one)
        view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.content).startAnimation(two)
        view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img).startAnimation(three)
      })
  }
}
```

If the animation still doesn't trigger you may try to hide views visibility and reveal them right before the animation.